# when run "printui.exe /s",it return error code 33 (error_lock_acess),how to fix it?

Tags: delphi, cmd

On Windows 7, I wantta open "print server property dialog" by printui.exe.in Delphi code :

```
a :=  'printui.exe /s';
showMessage(inttostr(winexec(PChar(a),5)));
```

pls,how to fix it?thx.BTW ,it is work very well when type command this :

```
 printui.exe /s
```

in cmd.exe.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec

Comment: thx.@DavidHeffernan.I've tried CreateProcess,but it does not work like WinExec.

Comment: Yes it does. Clearly you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `WinExec` returns return code 33 it actually means that the call to `winexec` was a sucsess. In fact any return value greater than 31 means sucsess.

[WinExec function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec)

The error code `33 error_lock_access` that you are mentioning in the title is actually a `System Error Code` not a return value of `WinExec` function itself

[System Error Codes (0-499)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Also as you can read in WinExec documentation under `Security remarks` it is actually not recomended to be useing WinExec but instead using [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) due to possible security vulnerability of `WinExec` function.

Comment: "*it is actually not recomended to be useing WinExec but instead using CreateProcess due to possible security vulnerability of WinExec function*" - also, because WinExec() is a legacy API for backwards compatibility with 16bit Windows. It just should not be used in modern code, period.